# how to set rabbitmq data directory to pvc in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I tried to create standalone rabbitmq kubernetes service. And the data should be mount to my persistent volume.

```
.....
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-config
data:
  enabled_plugins: |
      [rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s].
  rabbitmq.conf: |
        loopback_users.guest = false
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: standalone-rabbitmq
spec:
  serviceName: standalone-rabbitmq
  replicas: 1
  template:
        .....
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
          - name: standalone-rabbitmq-data
            mountPath: /data
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: rabbitmq-config
            items:
            - key: rabbitmq.conf
              path: rabbitmq.conf
            - key: enabled_plugins
              path: enabled_plugins
        - name: standalone-rabbitmq-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: standalone-rabbitmq-pvc-test
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: standalone-rabbitmq-pvc-test
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: test-storage-class
```

According to my research, I understood that data directory of rabbitmq is **RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR** (please see https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html). So I just wanted to set this parameter “/data”, so that my new PVC(standalone-rabbitmq-pvc-test) is used to keep the data.
Can you tell me how to configurate this?

Answer (score 1):

HTH, So pretty much here's my configuration. From which you can see there are mount points. First is the data, second is config and third is definitions respectively as in the YML mentioned below.

```
     volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/rabbitmq
      name: rmqdata
    - mountPath: /etc/rabbitmq
      name: config
    - mountPath: /etc/definitions
      name: definitions
      readOnly: true
```

And here's the PVC template stuff.

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: rmqdata
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
  storageClassName: nfs-provisioner
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

---

Post Update:  As per the comments, you can mount it directly to the `data` folder like this. The section where you assign the `rmqdata` to mountpath will stay the same.

```
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /data
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: rmqdata
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not get how to mount rmqdata to my pv which is "/data" directory. Also can you explain me why definitions are used?

Comment: So basicly the 'rmqdata' is the name of the PVC which is in most simplistic way a folder. 
Now In your case, I think you can just mount it to a folder on one of you nodes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the path, create a new file, let's say *'rabbitmq.properties'* and add all the environment variables you'll need, one per line:
`echo "RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR=/data" >> rabbitmq.properties`

Then run `kubectl create configmap rabbitmq-config --from-file=rabbitmq.properties` to generate the configmap.

If you need to aggregate multiple config files in one configmap point the folder's full path in the `--from-file` argument

Then you can run  `kubectl get configmaps rabbitmq-config -o yaml` 
to display the yaml that was created:

```
user@k8s:~$ kubectl get configmaps rabbitmq-config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  rabbitmq.properties: |
    RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR=/data
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-12-30T11:33:27Z"
  name: rabbitmq-config
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1106939"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/rabbitmq-config
  uid: 4c6b1599-a54b-4e0e-9b7d-2799ea5d9e39
```

If all other aspects of your configmap is correct, you can just add in the data section of your configmap this lines:

```
  rabbitmq.properties: |
    RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR=/data
```